# PHPStorm How to keep last opened file?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 10.0 now. Usually when I open PHPStorm, files that I opened last time will be there. But recently they are missing, so is navigation column. 
The option: Reopen last project on startup is always checked.

Please help. It is kind of annoying every time you need to remember what files you were working on.

Comment: It automatically reopens all my old projects and files for me.

Comment: Have you tried opening a support request with JetBrains?

Comment: Can confirm, opens up for me too.

Comment: 1) Does it happen with all projects or just particular one? 2) Try disabling all 3rd party (not installed by default) plugins -- any difference?

Comment: I installed PHPStorm 10.0(was 9.0) still acted like this.

Answer (score 7):

Delete `{your project}\.idea\workspace.xml`, then restart PHPStorm. Got it from JetBrains support.